# generate which button is shown

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton

i've got 5 buttons in my view and one of them is shown (4 hidden). now i want that when the shown button is pressed an ibaction starts which generates one of the 4 other buttons. after this the generated button should be shown.

how could this generating method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your question: you need to generate 4 buttons when another one is pressed:

```
-(IBAction) generateBtns:(UIButton*) sender {
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
        UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setFrame: CGRectMake: (x, y, w, h)];
        [sender.superview addSubview: btn];
    }
}
```